# How can I share attribute between one function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make a game, also i have some problems in the code. I don't know why my code is giving error. The error is

> "AttributeError: 'BarreraControlable' object has no attribute 'abajo' "

```
class BarreraControlable(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self, xInicial, yInicial):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    self.image = pygame.image.load("animaciones/barrera.png") #barrera.png? .png necesario
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = xInicial
    self.rect.y = yInicial
    self.subir = -8
    self.bajar = 8
    self.incremento = self.bajar


def lecturaEventos(self):
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    self.abajo = False
    self.arriba = False

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.abajo = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.arriba = True
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        self.abajo = False
        self.arriba = False

def ejecutaPaso(self):
    if self.abajo == True:
        self.rect.y += self.incremento
    elif self.arriba == True:
        self.incremento = self.bajar
        self.rect.y += self.incremento

def update(self):
    self.ejecutaPaso()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `self.abajo` is created and assigned in the method `lectureEventos()`. Make sure that you have called `lectureEventos()` before you call `ejectutaPaso()` or `update()`.

Or you can make all attributes initialize in your constructor if you do not intend that they have to be initialized in the methods.